# Reading piped input

Tags: c++, linux, macos, pipe

I'm trying to get my head around pipes in OSX/Linux. I have a utility called foo. I want it to parse any input I pipe to it from some other arbitrary utility and exit if there is no input. I am currently reading the contents of cin, which works fine if I pass something to foo. However, if I do not pipe any content to foo, the read to cin blocks indefinitely.

Obviously I am doing something wrong/stupid. What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried typing the input with the keyboard and typed cntr+d when finished?

Comment: Blocking is the expected behaviour for programs that read from the standard input. Try running `cat` with no arguments, you'll see it has the same behaviour. Also try what @hetepeperfan suggested, which is what is expected of the user in these situations.

Comment: I've taken the suggestion above and just replicated the behaviour of the "cat" utility. it doesn't solve the problem but I can live with it. thank you syam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to exit when the input finishes running, just check if the standard input is still working. It will get an EOF when the input program is terminated.

```
while (cin.good()) {
    cin << whatever;
    ...
}
```

However, if you don't want to wait until the input program terminates, then you probably have to wait for some timeout. The simplest way is to use `select()` on file descriptor 0, then read only if there is data, then finish if there is a timeout. Or, if you want to do it the C++ way, I recommend [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). You can use [`posix::stream_descriptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html) for dealing with native file descriptors under Posix systems.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you for the suggestion to use select. Despite taking syam's suggestion in this case, it does appear to solve my problem. Also, I've learned something about file descriptors in the process. Thank you!